# UTF8 doesn't work in swedish

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have a swedish website, and whenever I write åäö in the code, it displays as åäö on the site, but when I enter åäö in the database (for exemple a text in the column 'description'), it outputs a square with a question mark on the website.

I have tried the

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF8" />
```

And

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
```

And

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

And all possible charsets (it feels like) but it doesn't work.

The MySQL connection collation is utf8_bin and the collation for the table column is utf8_swedish_ci.
Help?

EDIT:
If I edit the php.ini-file to have

```
default_charset = "utf8_unicode_ci"
```

and change the meta to

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8_general_ci" />
```

the åäö displays correctly, but the åäö from the code in the files display as Ã¤.

EDIT2: Well, the mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8'); solved my problem.

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).

Comment: maybe you are saving using `strtolower()` php function. it does damages the germanic umlauted word.

Answer (score 0):

1. `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF8" />` is wrong. Should be `UTF-8`.
2. Don't use `set names`. Use `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);` instead.
3. Check if your table has proper encoding.
4. Check if your source code file is `UTF-8` encoded.

PS. Please note that collation is not the same thing as encoding. You need to set table encoding, not collation. Collation has nothing to do with proper output encoding.

Comment: 1. Still doesn't work
2. (Doesn't get it to work)
3. All the tables have collation utf8_general_ci
4. The source code file is UTF-8
(Added a edit to the question)

Comment: Please note that collation is not the same thing as encoding. You need to set table encoding, not collation. Collation has nothing to do with proper output.